# Debug Version of Flash Player for Google TV

Tags: google-tv, flashplayer-debug

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain a Debug version of the Flash Player Chrome plugin for Google TV? I would like to remotely debug Flash applications running on a Google TV device, but as I understand it this requires a debug version of the player, and also a mechanism for entering the host name for the remote host where the debugger (e.g. Flash Builder) is running.

I did find an [article regarding Chrome](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html) on the Adobe web site, but there's no mention of Google TV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available.  Google TV is based on Android - [Flash support for android has been deprecated](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html).  As of this writing Google TV is based on Android 3.2 and continues to support Flash - Flash support is not expected for future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's not possible for users to update Flash in the current Chrome on Google TV so there is no way to go to a debug version of Flash.  Developers have to implement debugging code in your Action script.  Given the fact that Flash support will eventually be phased out, it makes more sense to look into other solutions more compatible with future versions of Android/Chrome on Google TV.